# Unix command with umlaut character execute from Robot Framework

Tags: unix, robotframework, robotframework-sshlibrary

I want to execute unix sed command from RobotFramwork.  Command is working working on Unix box but when same command execute from RobotFramework its not working.

Execute Command     sed 's/|[a-zA-Z0-9\~\Ö\ö]*[^a-zA-Z0-9\~\Ö\ö].*$/|/' File1.txt > file2.txt

*available data in File1*

```
01|ÖABCD

02|DEBF

03|YY&Y

04|1343
```

*output should be file2.txt*

```
01|ÖABCD

02|DEBF

03|

04|1343
```

When I execute this command from unix box it gives me correct result in file2.txt. However, when I execute same command from Robotframework this command is working for first record as Ö (umlaut) available in data.

Comment: Please show  how you are running it from within a robot test by [edit]ing your question to include a [mcve]

Comment: Execute Command  -  sed 's/|[a-zA-Z0-9\\~\\Ö\\ö]*[^a-zA-Z0-9\\~\\Ö\\ö].*$/|/' File1.txt > file2.txt

Comment: I have added this command here in robot Framework format only. Asfrom Robot Framework I need to add double slash (\\). However, when I execute same from Unix box then only 1 slash (\) is required. So above command is in Robot Framework only

Comment: Please don't add code in the comments. You can [edit]  your question to add more details. Code in the comments is almost impossible to read. Your comment shows a dash after the keyword name - is that really how you're doing it in robot?